# ubuntu 20.04 has two interface and rdp works only for the NAT Interface

Tags: rdp

I have two interfaces on the ubuntu server
Wireless Network connected to a netgear Router and it is NAT
The Wired interface 01 interface is connected to the L2 Switch other wired interface is connected to firewall
When I am connected to wireless network I can RDP on the NAT network to the ubuntu server
I cannot connect do RDP to the wired Network interface

```
ubuntu@OptiPlex-3050-02:~$ ip a s
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group defaul                                  t qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp1s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP gr                                  oup default qlen 1000
    link/ether b8:85:84:ad:a9:9d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.51.6/24 brd 192.168.51.255 scope global noprefixroute enp1s0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::ba85:84ff:fead:a99d/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: wlp2s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP gro                                  up default qlen 1000
    link/ether 14:4f:8a:ae:ea:4d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.20/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wl                                  p2s0
       valid_lft 85039sec preferred_lft 85039sec
    inet6 fe80::98eb:10dd:9545:342e/64 scope link noprefixroute
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: enxe00000101db5: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel st                                  ate UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether e0:00:00:10:1d:b5 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.253.210/24 brd 192.168.253.255 scope global noprefixroute enxe0                                  0000101db5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::e200:ff:fe10:1db5/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
ubuntu@OptiPlex-3050-02:~$
```

Comment: From what I can see they are not in the same subnet so you might have a NAT configuration problem that is not forwarding from the 192.168.1.x subnet to the 192.168.51.x subnet or vice versa.

Comment: Please add the output of `ip route` to your question.